# How to initialize an array of object in Ruby

Tags: ruby

can anyone tell me how to initialize an array of object in Ruby. I have my class Line:

```
class Line
  @@text
  @@number = 0
  @@file = 0
  @@paired

  def initialize(text, number, file = 0, paired = 1)
    @@text = text
    @@number = number
    @@file = file
    @@paired = paired
  end
end
```

And now i wish to initialize an Array of Lines, when i do 
`parsedLines = Array.new()` and in 
`loop do parsedLines[i] = Line.new(line, number, file, 0)`
i got an array of Lines, but Array elements are initialize on last made Line object, how can i fix this, to have array of Line object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `@@` does. It defines a class-level variable, shared by all instances of the class. Each time you declare a new instance, you're overwriting those values, so of course your entire array will appear to contain the same object.

Change `@@` to `@` in your `initialize` method, and remove the class-level `@@` variables completely, they serve no purpose. You do not need to declare variables this way in Ruby.

The correct implementation would be:

```
class Line
  def initialize(text, number = 0, file = 0, paired = 1)
    @text = text
    @number = number
    @file = file
    @paired = paired
  end
end
```